# Android: managedQuery returns 0 records when looking for images, Where is it looking for the images?

Tags: android, android-emulator

nyone can help. I am trying to get all available pictures on the sdcard. I have placed images (JPG) into the sdcard and pictures directory but the following code always returns 0 records.

```
    // Set up an array of the Thumbnail Image ID column we want
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};
    // Create the cursor pointing to the SDCard
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection, // Which columns to return
            null,       // Return all rows
            null,       
            null);
```

Where is this code actually looking? Because it is not picking up any images that i have placed in Pictures / DCIM as well (in the emulator).

EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI points to which directory on the sdcard?

I know I am doing something wrong, any ideas what?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

After reading some comments i may be doing this wrong?

I need to display some images in a specific directory on the sdcard .. this directory will not have been imported to the gallery....

So the Cursor is not of any use here?

The cursor is only for searching the database of the gallery?

Is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: are the pics visible in gallery. Because if you have downloaded them, unless media scanner has run the db will not be updated

Comment: Ahh this only works with pictures imported to the gallery for example, ahhh I need to grab images in a directory.... these are private images. I will update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the pictures are in your own directory and Mediasccanner is not scanning them, then the db will not have your pictures data. So then you cannot use the query to get these pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

First obtain the ContentResolver object by using getContentResolver();

```
Cursor cursor = cr.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                        null, null, null, null);
```

For More Information Look at this [Tutorial](http://androidhub.wordpress.com/2011/09/27/query-mediastore-contentprovider-for-images-stored-in-sdcard/).

[Really Nice Tutorials](http://mobile.dzone.com/news/displaying-images-sd-card)

Answer (score 0):

The application need to

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```